# Rebuilding deceased email server: moving to postfix?

Tags: centos, postfix, sendmail

We had to relocate our servers to a new facility recently. After the move our email server ( sendmail, RHEL ) is DOA. I have all the files on tape but this gives me the opportunity to move to postfix (esp since it appears the original sendmail.mc is gone). Some questions about such a move:

1. Does postfix require a chroot jail?
2. I have the passwd, shadow, etc files from the orig server - can I copy in the relevant entries to my new server or do I need to recreate these?
3. Does postfix even use linux accounts? (finding conflicting answers to this)
4. All the mailbox data is (obviously) tailored to sendmail. Can postfix read these same structures or do they need to be ported somehow? (more conflicting answers)
5. Most of what I've read says that postfix accounts and such should be in a DB (postgres or mysql) - is this necc?

This is not intended to be a religious 'postfix vs sendmail' type question. I'm fairly certain that I'm migrating - just not 100% clear on the full path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does postfix require a chroot jail?

No, he doesn't

> I have the passwd, shadow, etc files from the orig server - can I copy in the relevant entries to my new server or do I need to recreate these?

only if the crypt method are the same

> Does postfix even use linux accounts? (finding conflicting answers to this)

Yes, postfix by default using system accounts

> All the mailbox data is (obviously) tailored to sendmail. Can postfix read these same structures or do they need to be ported somehow? (more conflicting answers)

As far as I know sendmail supports mailbox and maildir. Postfix can handle both of them, so there is no problem at all

> Most of what I've read says that postfix accounts and such should be in a DB (postgres or mysql) - is this necc?

No, it's not necessary. But for security reasons it's a good practice to use virtual accounts. Moreover, if you have a lot of domains it's very easy to manage all of them via postfixadmin